# How can I manage the migration process from Universal Analytics to GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics, web-analytics

I have a question for all of you. I’m assuming everyone knows about this whole Universal Analytics being replaced by Google Analytics 4. I watched a lot of videos, read a good amount of articles but I’m still in doubt about how I’m going to manage my new GA4 account. How did you guys pull it off? Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

GA interface started to show reminder about UA sunset in May. I have followed the instructions and created a GA4 property along UA property that is still working. The numbers in UA and GA4 are a little different but I am Ok with that. My website is a simple blog and there is nothing fancy there but everything works fine so far.

Comment: Hi Oleg, did you change your code? are you using gtag or ga?